# Corrupt audio file after copying over bluetooth stream

Tags: android, file, sockets, audio, bluetooth

I am sending a audio file by sending it over a bluetooth socket connection to another device. I am copying byte for byte, so the size on the other end is exactly the same.
However, when I try to play the file on the other end, I just get awkward noises (each time i start the player it sounds a little different).

Now the strange part: As soon as I copy the "corrupt" file to another location (via some android file manager), I can play it and it sounds totally fine!

Any ideas?

**sending:**

```
outputStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
long totalLength = file.length();
String command = Protocol.COMMAND_SEND_FILE + Protocol.SEPARATOR + file.getName() + Protocol.SEPARATOR + totalLength;
outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
outputStream.flush();

long bytesWritten = 0;
while ((c = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, c);
    outputStream.flush();

    bytesWritten += c;
}
mLogger.log("sent total of bytes", bytesWritten+"");
is.close();
```

**receiving:**

```
while (mRunning) {

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (!mReceiveFile) {
        bytesRead = mInputStream.read(buffer);
        if (bytesRead != -1) {
            String result = "";
            while ((bytesRead == bufferSize) && (buffer[bufferSize] != 0)) {
                result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = mInputStream.read(buffer);
            }
            result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            sb.append(result);
        }
    } else {
        if (mLogger != null) {
            mLogger.log("receiving file", mReceiveFilename);
        }
        int c = 0;
        long bRead = 0;
        OutputStream oos = new FileOutputStream(Utils.getAppRootDir() + "/" + mReceiveFilename);

        while (bRead < mReceiveFileLength && (c = mInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            if ((bRead + bufferSize) >= mReceiveFileLength) {
                c = (int) (mReceiveFileLength - bRead);
                mLogger.log("rest bytes", "" + c);
            }
            if(bRead < 10000 || bRead + 10000 > mReceiveFileLength){
                mLogger.log(new String(buffer));
            }
            oos.write(buffer, 0, c);
            oos.flush();
            bRead += c;
            mLogger.log("read " + bRead + " of " + mReceiveFileLength + " bytes");
        }
        oos.close();


        mLogger.log("saved file", mReceiveFilename);


        mReceiveFile = false;
        mReceiveFilename = null;

    }
    if (sb.toString().startsWith(Protocol.COMMAND_SEND_FILE)) {
        // "SEND_FILE:filename.ext"
        try {
            String[] command = sb.toString().split(Protocol.SEPARATOR);
            mReceiveFile = true;
            mReceiveFilename = command[1];
            mReceiveFileLength = Long.parseLong(command[2]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLogger.log("Protocoll exception command could not be parsed:" + sb.toString());
        }
    } else {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new BluetoothCommunicator(sb.toString()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I have to start the media scanner after creating the new file. After that it plays like a charm!

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
```